# The method 'forEach' was called on null in my flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, hybrid

i have problem with my forEach, dataList is null
this my code :

```
Future<List<Widget>> createList()async{
List<Widget> items = new List<Widget>();
String dataString = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/data.json");
List<dynamic> dataJSON = jsonDecode(dataString);

dataJSON.forEach((object) {
  String finalString="";
  List<dynamic> dataList = object["placeItems"];
  dataList.forEach((item) {
    finalString = finalString + item + " | ";
  });
```

> this my json data :

```
[
    {
        "placeImage":"images/fish2.jpg",
        "placeName":"Ikan 2",
        "placeItem":["fish, crab, seafood"],
        "minOrder":20
    },

]
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a simplified version of your code in this [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/6ef0374a9f5f43fe7b859d09301a7b33)

You are making two mistakes, the first is that the JSON is invalid due to the comma after the first object of the list, and the second is you are trying to obtain

```
object["placeItems"];
```

Which is misspelled it should be "placeItem". 
I suggest you look a little bit more at your code before submitting it to SO. And also to check a bit more about JSON structure [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp).
(Hint)The comma separated values inside placeItems are just one item in the list because they are on the same string.
Happy coding!